# Matching KeyPath in application with Wallet32 Keypath for Bip44 wallets

Tags: c#, bitcoin

I have an application where I create an HD wallet with a passphrase and save the public master key to the database for the user.

Then, I want the user to be able to back up the wallet to their own wallet, in this case I am using Wallet32. I restore the account in Wallet32, which uses a key path of m/44'/0'/0'/

On my application side, I am creating the keypath like so (in c#):

```
KeyPath newKeyPath = new KeyPath("44/0/0/0/0" + nextDerivation);
var childKey = pubkey.Derive(newKeyPath);
```

The nextDerivsation variable just increments with each purchase. When the derived public key is created on the application side, it doesn't match up with a derived public key in wallet32. So, if a payment is made through the application, Wallet32 doesn't pick it up.

I am using the C# NBitcoin library. When I try to add the apostrophes in the keyPath string like so:

```
KeyPath newKeyPath = new KeyPath("44'/0'/0'/0/0" + nextDerivation);
var childKey = pubkey.Derive(newKeyPath);
```

Then I get an "invalid input format" error. I am unsure as to whether those apostrophes are necessary or not, but when I input that same derivation path into the Bip32 generator, then I can create the same public keys. I can send a payment to the derived address and wallet32 picks it up.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on what I need to use for the KeyPath in the NBitcoin library to obtain the same results?

Answer (score -1):

for more timely responses, don't hesitate to ask on github, so I get notified.

My guess is that the 44' means that Wallet32 is using the "hardened key" 44, contrary to just 44 that mean you use the non hardened key 44 (more info in BIP32)

I am not aware of such notation, I can support it in NBitcoin, since I think it is useful, but I need some test data, would you generate some for me ?

Right now, if you want to make it works, consider key 44' as equal to (44u | (1u << 31)) in other words, 44 with the first bit to 1 to say it is hardened.

I can investigate that more deeply and implement it right into NBitcoin if you can give me an example of (Root HD Key + path  + Child HD Key)

[UPDATE]

Implemented in 1.0.7.10 at (https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin/commit/ce5b70d6d27d7fc2cedd089bfd1133a6cd490c97)

Your code should work as is, run Update-Package NBitcoin your solution, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I am right reading here :
https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki


Implementing it, you'll just have to do a Update-Package to make it works